# Migrate Project to Gradle?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Migrate Project to Gradle? This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system.**

After installing flutter plugins for Android Studio, when I run my first flutter app I got this warning. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Project Structure > Settings.gradle (Open it and add-- include ':app'; .

Step 2: Goto Gradle Tab (It normally present on Left or Right of Android Studio or intellij IDEA) > Then click to Refresh All Gradle Project

Comment: please refer this one as well https://coderwall.com/p/npki6q/migrate-existing-android-project-to-gradle